# How to find unique values in the results set

Tags: sql

I am still a SQL learner and I am trying to create a report but apparently I'm missing something:

There are two tables and I have written the below code:

```
SELECT t0.cardcode , t1.U_BOY_85_ECAT
from OCRD t0 JOIN 
     OCPR t1
     on t1.cardcode = t0.cardcode
order by t0.CardCode ASC;
```

*---------------------------------

```
cardcode    U_BOY_85_ECAT
0639    AUTOINV
1STOPAUT    AUTOINV
1STOPAUT    NULL
361WHEELS   
3POINTMOTORS    
3POINTMOTORS    100
3POINTMOTORS    NULL
4WDWS   AUTOINV
4x4ORC  AUTOINV
4X4SOL  100
888MOT  AUTOINV
888MOT
```

---------------------------------*

I want to pull a report to find only the values that does not have any contact name called autoinv. So the expeceted result from the above report should be NOT show cardcodes like 888MOT because one of its contacts is AUTOINV.

And even if I add (**Group by t0.cardcode , t1.U_BOY_85_ECAT**) , (or select distinct...), I'll get the same result set. it's less than a month since I started learning sql. thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Values of what?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cardcodes that don't have that contact, you can use aggregation or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t0.cardcode
FROM OCRD t0 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM OCPR t1
                  WHERE t1.cardcode = t0.cardcode AND t1.U_BOY_85_ECAT = 'AUTOINV'
                 );
```